# c MSI GE70 laptop shows Aptio setup utitlity endlessly - many solutions tried but non working

Tags: windows-10, boot, laptop, battery, msi-laptop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4coE.jpg)My MSI GE70 (Model Name MS-1756) {Boot version E1756IMS.513 / EC version 1756EMS1 Ver5.05} suddenly got stuck while I was running and operating on several desktop applications, and then removed the battery to kill the stuck. After reinstalling the battery it shows me the Aptio setup utility.

I searched on YouTube, Microsoft forums and google search engine and did not find any helpful tips as I tried almost all possible options that a user can find online. I expected these tips could make system restore or adjust the booting process to normal and makes the Windows 10 work fine again.

1. I tried optimized defaults.
2. Boot mode changing from 'Legacy' to 'UEFI (with CSM)'
3. I Tried many others different suggestions but none worked.

I've added a screenshot below of my PC

How do I restore my ability to boot into my Windows 10 installation?

Comment: Try this : Reboot and in the Aptio Setup Utility window go to Settings and look for an option like "Reset Configuration Data" or "Factory reset" to reset the BIOS to factory settings, save the change and reboot.

Comment: I can't find such an option in the current Aptio utility menu. What to do?

Comment: removed the battery to kill the stuck. After reinstalling the battery ....  Was the battery not fully charged?  Needs to be for updating BIOS.  It appears that you may have damaged the BIOS.

Comment: Exactly that is what I did unfortunately, and so the BIOS is really damaged?

Comment: The BIOS is the likely problem, the cause is perhaps an electrical surge. Perhaps your Aptio version is different - could you add a screenshot of its screen?

Comment: Ok, but which page you want its pic {Main ; Advanced ; Boot ; Security ; Save & Exit}?

Comment: Under Save & Exit, you should have Restore Defaults. See this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oGf9iTY--dY).

Comment: I just tried it, but it didn't work, unfortunately.